# Openid Connect, what to do with access_token and refresh_token?

Tags: access-token, openid-connect

From what I understand from this [blog post](http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/07/how-simple-is-openid-connect-basic.html), in openid connect, we use the id token to verify that the user is authenticated. Why does the response include an access token and a refresh token? Also the blog doesn't mentioned about verifying who sent the token. How do we verify that it is actually the idp that sent the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article describes the Basic Client Profile in which the client gets the tokens from the IDP on a backchannel call to the token endpoint. The SSL server certificate verification of the server certificate presented on the token endpoint guarantees that we're dealing with the correct IDP, which may obsolete the need for verifying the id_token separately.

An access token is included to make it possible for the client to make a call to the so-called User Info endpoint and get more claims about the user. That endpoint is an API that is protected using OAuth 2.0, hence the client needs to present an access token. Moreover, since OpenID Connect is based on OAuth 2.0, the access token may be associated with more scopes so that it can be used against other (non-OpenID Connect) APIs as well (regular OAuth 2.0).

The refresh token is included for regular OAuth 2.0 reasons, so that the client can get a new access token when the old one expires without involving explicit user authentication again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say `The SSL server certificate verification of the server certificate presented on the token endpoint` are you referring to the certificate used in the https communication?

Comment: Also when you say `verifying the id_token` do you mean verifying the signature (using a secret+hashing or RSA as indicated at http://jwt.io/)?